# async await function in useEffect returns same data on loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, async-await

I'm fetching svgs from multiavatar api but the issue is when i write the function in useEffect it gives me same value four times. But when i make the useEffect async it shows me different values.

I just want to know why it is happening?

It is showing me 4 different images.

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const image = await axios.get(
        `${api}/${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}`
      );
      const buffer = new Buffer(image.data);
      data.push(buffer.toString("base64"));
    }
    setAvatars(data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

This shows me same image 4 times

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const data = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const image = await axios.get(
          `${api}/${Math.round(Math.random) * 1000}`
        );
        const buffer = new Buffer(image.data);
        data.push(buffer.toString("base64"));
      }
      setAvatars(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    loadData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: The first implementation is invalid since the `useEffect` hook callback ***can't*** be `async`. Other than this I don't understand what you are asking. Which code behavior are you expecting to work and what is the expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese i want the to fix the code in which async function is called.But the issue is the random number is same on each iteration and i'm getting the same value 4 times

Comment: Maybe try calling the random function? Instead of `Math.round(Math.random) * 1000` use `Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)`. This appears to be an issue caused by a typo. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1):

The random number was not generating because of syntax error.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const data = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const image = await axios.get(
          `${api}/${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}`
        );
        const buffer = new Buffer(image.data);
        data.push(buffer.toString("base64"));
      }
      setAvatars(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    loadData();
  }, []);
```